Error in "as.ltraj" in r: "Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 1206, 0"
I am trying to work out the tortuosity of echidna movement using GPS data from 10 individuals. The tags were programmed to take hourly fixes, however, since echidnas often are in burrows, the success rate of the fixes was not particularly high. Regardless, I managed to get over 60 000 data points over a couple of months but now I am really struggling with "as.ltraj" in the "adehabitatLT" package in R 4.2.2. This is the code that I have:
# Load necessary libraries
library(adehabitatLT)
library(amt)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# Read in csv file
echidna_data <- read.csv("GPS_2022_2023.csv")

# Check the structure of the data
str(echidna_data)

# Convert 'Date_time' to POSIXct Timestamp
echidna_data <- echidna_data %>%
  mutate(Timestamp = dmy_hm(Date_time, tz = "UTC"))

# Ensure the conversion is correct
print(head(echidna_data))

# Remove potential duplicate timestamps for each ID - I don't think I should need to do this
echidna_data <- echidna_data %>%
  arrange(ID, Timestamp) %>%
  group_by(ID, Timestamp) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1) %>%
  ungroup()
# Select relevant columns
echidna_data <- echidna_data %>%
  select(ID, Timestamp, Latitude, Longitude)

# Ensure no missing values in critical columns
echidna_data <- echidna_data %>%
  filter(!is.na(Latitude) & !is.na(Longitude) & !is.na(Timestamp) & !is.na(ID))

# Check the structure of the data after cleaning
print(head(echidna_data))

# Ensure the data frame dimensions are correct
nrow(echidna_data)
ncol(echidna_data)


# Ensure no missing values in critical columns again
echidna_data <- echidna_data %>%
  filter(!is.na(Latitude) & !is.na(Longitude) & !is.na(Timestamp) & !is.na(ID))

# Ensure the data frame dimensions are correct
print(paste("Number of rows:", nrow(echidna_data)))
print(paste("Number of columns:", ncol(echidna_data)))

# Print a sample to ensure data is as expected
print(head(echidna_data))

# Additional check: Ensure ID is a factor
echidna_data <- echidna_data %>%
  mutate(ID = as.factor(ID))

# Check for unique timestamps within each ID
timestamp_check <- echidna_data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(unique_timestamps = n_distinct(Timestamp), total_rows = n())

print(head(timestamp_check))

# **this is where the problem is**
# Create ltraj object
ltraj_data <- as.ltraj(xy = echidna_data[, c("Longitude", "Latitude")], date = echidna_data$Timestamp, id = echidna_data$ID, typeII = TRUE)

# Calculate the distance of each segment
ltraj_data_segments <- ld(ltraj_data)

# Ensure segments are calculated correctly
print(head(ltraj_data_segments))

# Summing the lengths of segments
total_distance <- sum(ltraj_data_segments$dist, na.rm = TRUE)
print(total_distance)

# Summing the lengths of segments
total_distance <- sum(ltraj_data_segments$dist, na.rm = TRUE)

# Calculate Euclidean distance between the first and last point for each echidna
calculate_sinuosity <- function(data) {
  start_point <- data[1, c("x", "y")]
  end_point <- data[nrow(data), c("x", "y")]
  euclidean_distance <- sqrt(sum((start_point - end_point)^2))
  actual_path_length <- sum(data$dist, na.rm = TRUE)
  sinuosity <- actual_path_length / euclidean_distance
  return(sinuosity)
}

# Apply to each echidna's data
library(dplyr)

sinuosity_results <- gps_data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(sinuosity = map_dbl(data, ~ calculate_sinuosity(ld(as.ltraj(xy = .x[, c("x", "y")], date = .x$timestamp, id = .x$id)))))

# View results
print(sinuosity_results)


You can see there are a lot of checks, the number of rows for each of the 4 columns (ID, Timestamp, Lat, Long) is 8375. There are no n/as or null values but I keep getting stuck at the bold section with this error:

Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 1206, 0

ChatGPT has not been able to help, I think I need real people help on this one. Any suggestions?
Here is a sample of the simplified data - the original data has over 40 columns:
ID            Timestamp  Latitude  Longitude
E1  2022-08-28 13:00:00 -31.68469   150.6052
E1  2022-08-28 14:00:00 -31.68448   150.6054
E1  2022-08-28 15:00:00 -31.68425   150.6067
E1  2022-08-28 16:00:00 -31.68382   150.6066
E1  2022-08-28 17:00:00 -31.68386   150.6062
E1  2022-08-28 18:00:00 -31.68396   150.6059
E1  2022-08-28 19:00:00 -31.68458   150.6055
E1  2022-08-28 20:00:00 -31.68519   150.605
E1  2022-08-28 21:00:00 -31.68505   150.6052
E1  2022-08-28 22:00:00 -31.68494   150.6057
E1  2022-08-29 02:00:00 -31.68512   150.6051
E1  2022-08-29 05:00:00 -31.68502   150.605
E1  2022-08-29 09:00:00 -31.6851    150.6051
E1  2022-08-29 10:00:00 -31.68506   150.605
E1  2022-08-29 11:00:00 -31.68454   150.6052
E1  2022-08-29 12:00:00 -31.68392   150.6049
E1  2022-08-29 13:00:00 -31.68374   150.6053
E1  2022-08-29 14:00:00 -31.68331   150.6055
E1  2022-08-29 15:00:00 -31.68256   150.6057
E1  2022-08-29 16:00:00 -31.68232   150.6049
E1  2022-08-29 17:00:00 -31.68251   150.6057
E1  2022-08-29 18:00:00 -31.68307   150.6066
E1  2022-08-29 19:00:00 -31.68372   150.6069
E1  2022-08-29 20:00:00 -31.68456   150.6062
E1  2022-08-29 21:00:00 -31.68496   150.6056
E1  2022-08-29 22:00:00 -31.68489   150.6061
E1  2022-08-29 23:00:00 -31.68497   150.6061
E1  2022-08-30 00:00:00 -31.68492   150.6062
E1  2022-08-30 01:00:00 -31.68491   150.6062
E1  2022-08-30 02:00:00 -31.68492   150.6062
E1  2022-08-30 03:00:00 -31.68492   150.6061
E1  2022-08-30 04:00:00 -31.68513   150.6061

Thanks.
